# Dynamically create divs with height and width

Tags: jquery, dom, html

I'm dynamically creating divs in my application, and wants through parameters in a function to choose the width and height of the divs. The code below works, however I don't want to add styling directly to my HTML document which it does.

Is there another way to accomplish this without adding css to the HTML document?

```
function createDiv(theWidth, theHeight){

var box = $('<div/>', {
   'class': 'box',
   'width': theWidth,
   'height': theHeight,
}).appendTo('#content');

}
```

Note: The height and width is retrieved from a JSON-file through AJAX and can differ. By that reason I can't create different classes with different heights and widths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either:

- Add a predefined class to the div, or
- Add a style attribute with the contents

Why "I don't want to add styling"??

Edit:

```
function createDiv(theWidth, theHeight){

    $('<div class=\'box\' style=\'width:'+theWidth+'px;height:'+theHeight+'px;\'/>').appendTo('#content');

}
```

Comment: I just want the html document plain and clean, and therefore don't want it to contain styling, ie. all the styling should be in the css file.

Comment: It doesn't matter, because the CSS is only loaded after the page has loaded, so it isn't actually added to the "source" code. You will be able to see the style in e.g. FireBug, but if you look at the source, it is not there.

Comment: I don't think I get it? Predefined classes isn't an option because I can't know the heights and widths (retrieved from a JSON-file through AJAX). Adding the height and width as I do it with my code adds inline style to the HTML document.

Comment: Ya, but it only adds inline styles after the page has loaded, so don't worry about "clean". This is the most efficient way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to define the height and width in a CSS file, and add the appropriate class to your new element.

```
.box {
  height: ...;
  width: ...;
}

var box = $('<div/>', {
    class: 'box'
}).appendTo('#content');
```

Or

```
var box = $("<div/>").addClass("box").appendTo("$content");
```

Comment: Yes, I know but the problem is (which I should have mentioned) that the height and width is retrieved through AJAX (JSON) and the thing is that the height and width can differ.

Comment: @JasonCraig If the values are dynamic, you have no choice but to establish them with JavaScript. You cannot manipulate the CSS files with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The only other way I can see this happening is by returning in your JSON result a style element  with some auto-generated class containing the new width and height. You will add the style to your document and then add the class to the element. Here is a sample:

```
$(function(){
    var json = {
        cssClass: "random1",
        style: "<style type='text/css'>.random1{width:200px;height:200px}</style>"};

    alert("Wait");
    $("head").append(json.style);
    $("div").addClass(json.cssClass);
});
```

For a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/epignosisx/YNpFV/